# How to delete object on the heap when another heap object is deleted

Tags: c++, qt, delete-operator

I have the following source code:

```
void Processmethod()
{
    QDialog *ProcessMessage = new QDialog;      
    Ui::DialogProcessMessage *Dialog = new Ui::DialogProcessMessage();              
    Dialog->setupUi(ProcessMessage);              //polymorphy
    ProcessMessage->setModal(true);
    ProcessMessage->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    connect(Dialog->pushButtonAbort, SIGNAL(clicked()), &Prozess, SLOT(kill()));  
    connect(&Prozess6, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)),  this, SLOT(helper()));
    connect(&Prozess6, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)),  this, SLOT(helper()));
 connect(this,SIGNAL(enablePushButton(bool)),Dialog->pushButtonClose, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));
    Prozessmeldung->setModal(true);
    ProcessMessage->show();

    processmethodONE();
}
```

How can I delete the heap-object Dialog best when the heap-object ProcessMessage is deleted (which is deleted when closed)? Both objects must be created on the heap. Furthermore the class "Ui::DialogProcessMessage" is directly created by the ui-file and therefore any changes in it will be deleted everytime the ui-file is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All instances of QObject emit a `destroyed(QObject*)` signal when they are deleted. Connect `ProcessMessage`'s signal to some other persistent object's slot, and delete your `Dialog` heap-object from there.

Ref.: [Qt documentation for QObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#destroyed)

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass QDialog, add field in new class for your sub object assign it when creating and add destructor who will free memory of subojbects when your CustomNewSubclassedQDialog if destroyed.

Comment: Is there no stable way without subclassing? I mean, I just want to delete the object `Dialog`.

Comment: you could use boost:smart_ptr to handle this ref or scoped_ptr but you have to read more on how they work and what are the implications of them.

Eg. you can have shared_ptr, you can read more here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can `delete` the `Dialog` object in `ProcessMessage`'s destructor.

You'll have to document this to make it clear that `ProcessMessage` is responsible for the `Dialog`. Note that this doesn't seem like a good idea. The best approach here is to manually delete both objects when you're done with them. There's nothing restricting anyone from creating a `Dialog` in automatic storage, which when attempted to be deleted might cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Problem is that Ui::DialogProcessMessage is directly created by the ui-file and when changing the ui-file your add to the class Ui::DialogProcessMessage would be lost. Furthermore I don`t know how to manually delete the object dialog since it needs to be used until the object ProcessMessage is closed. And: ProcessMessage is a QDialogs class object which I can't define.

Answer (score 1):

Is `Ui::DialogProcessMessage` a class of your own? Is it derived from `QObject`? If so, pass the `ProcessMessage` pointer to the `Dialog` constructor as its `parent`. That way `ProcessMessage` becomes responsible for deleting `Dialog`. I.e. your declaration of the `Ui::DialogProcessMessage` class should look something like this:

```
namespace Ui
{
class DialogProcessMessage: public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  DialogProcessMessage(QObject* parent=0) :
    QDialog(parent)
  { /* ... */ }

  /*
   * more stuff ...
   */
};
}
```

And then, construct `Dialog` as follows:

```
Ui::DialogProcessMessage *Dialog = new Ui::DialogProcessMessage(ProcessMessage);
```

You might want to refer to the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html) for more information.

Comment: yes, `Ui::DialogProcessMessage` is a class of my own and I created it with the QtDesigner. I am not really sure if it is derived from QObject since there is no QObject class mentioned in it, but the elements of `Ui::DialogProcessMessage` like pushButtons etc. at least should derive from QObject. Problem is that `Ui::DialogProcessMessage` is directly created by the ui-file and when changing the ui-file your add to the class `Ui::DialogProcessMessage` would be lost.

Comment: Then that is a different scenario from what you described in your question. I think [this](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Using_Qt_Designer) should help.